# Should we use [horror] or [horror-gaming]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed we have two competing tags, [horror](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) and [horror-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror-gaming).  I was going to synonym them as horror-gaming->horror but I noticed horror-gaming has more uses than horror.

A tag of horror-gaming seems weird to me - the entire site scope is about gaming, so it seems redundant. Our other [setting tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/should-we-use-setting-tags) aren't e.g. [fantasy-gaming], but just [fantasy].

Should I merge [horror-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror-gaming) into [horror](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)?

Comment: Yes.<!-------->

Comment: Yep. Argh, comment length.

Comment: Added this synonym.

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, [horror](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) should be the primary tag.

I suspect that [horror-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror-gaming) gets used because while we're comfortable with fantasy as a familiar gaming genre, horror is a little more niche. There may be a sense (especially upon seeing the choice of both tags come up) that the -gaming bit helps clarify things.

But it seems unneeded to me, for the reasons brought up in your question. [horror](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) is fine and dandy.

Comment: I think you've identified the source of the tag. [horror] isn't immediately obvious as a genre, rather than simply a emotion/event/topic of discussion, so we get (unnecessary) clarifications like [horror-gaming] to capture the genre. I think we can safely treat any question that asks about how to handle horror in game, but isn't explicitly a horror-gaming-genre question, as a horror-genre question anyway. That's where the expertise will come from after all, even if the GM isn't self-identifying the campaign as horror genre.

Comment: I've proposed a tag wiki for [tag:horror] to help with the clarification.